# Android c2dm unknown permissions

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

I've seen a very similar question was posted but his solution didn't help. I'm seeing unknown permission in the warn section of logcat.

```
unknown permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE in package com.upmc

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.upmc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="com.upmc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

     <!-- registers the receiving class for a c2dm broadcast intent to be .C2DMBroadcastReceiver.-->

    <receiver android:name=".C2DMReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <!--Action String being listened for, then calls parent registered receiver -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <!-- still don't understand this  -->
            <catagory android:name="com.upmc" />
            <!-- must unregister intent filter when app is not running -->
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- change here...action string pre-set by google?-->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <!-- specify under what circumstances the action should be serviced -->
            <catagory android:name="com.upmc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Hard to read i know sorry!

I'm also not getting a response of any kind from google. I've registered this app and am signed into a google account. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you building your project with the Google APIs? I make a mistake every now and then of not building with Google APIs, but it's easy to check and fix if you haven't. Right-click your project, click on `Properties`, click on `Android` in the left-hand sidebar, and check what's your build target. Check the Google APIs version if you haven't.

Comment: Yes, I am building with the Google API's. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#c2dm_permissions), to use C2DM in your application to have to register the following permissions

1. com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
2. android.permission.INTERNET

And also refer to this question: [C2DM: How to use C2D_MESSAGE permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121061/c2dm-how-to-use-c2d-message-permission)