# Can I receive another Android app's C2DM Intents if I'm signed with the same signature?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm, android-permissions

I have an app (`com.example.myapp`) installed that received `C2DM` `Intent`s. I would like to piggyback onto this to perform my own processing in response to these `Intent`s in a separate app (`com.example.myapp2`). According to the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121330/9636), the `C2DM` client system looks for:

> broadcast receivers for Intent:
> `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION`
>
> That have the permission:
> `.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`

In the original app, the following permission is defined and used, [as specified in the C2DM Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest)

```
  <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
   <permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

This is `com.example.myapp2`'s manifest, in which I use that permission also:

```
<manifest package="com.example.myapp2" ...>

   <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
   <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

   <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

   <!-- Send the registration id to the server -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application...>
      <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it --> 
      <receiver android:name=".C2DMReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <!-- Receive the actual message -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
              <category android:name="com.example.myapp2" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      ...
   </application>
   ...
</manifest>
```

My `C2DMReceiver` is `com.example.myapp2.C2DMReceiver`. Notice that I'm not listening for `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` `Intent`s since I don't care about registering. I only care about receiving the `Intent`s that `com.example.myapp` is already receiving. In my `IntentFilter` for `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` `Intent`s, I filter for both `com.example.myapp` and `com.example.myapp2` `category`s since `C2DM` isn't specific about exactly what a `C2DM` `Intent` looks like. Any help there would be appreciated.

I've verified that `com.example.myapp2` has the `com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE` permission. If I run with a debug key, I don't have it, but if I run with the release key, I have it. Obviously, I'm running the version on my device with the release key.

When `com.example.myapp` receives a `C2DM` `Intent` `com.example.myapp2` doesn't receive it. Any ideas for how to debug or how to get this to work? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK This is not possible.  When an app registers for C2DM messages it generates a key that is based on the package name of the app and you can only have one of those per device.

If you are using the same signature then I'm assuming you control both apps, if so you'd have to have the app that receives the C2DM message transmit the data to the second app via a service to which they both have access.

Comment: Can you point to some documentation somewhere that talks about the key? I haven't found anything definitive. All the docs talk about posting the broadcast intent, and requiring the C2D_MESSAGE permission.

Comment: "An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive messages for a given Android application. In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device."

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: It's the same.  The backend for GCM and C2DM are exactly the same.  The only thing that changed is the name, the quota and the client sdk does more for you now that it used to.  The rest is exactly the same.

Comment: "applicationPackage + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE prevents other applications from registering and receiving the application's messages." from https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest implies that you can register for another application's messages if you have the permission, which I have.