# C2D_MESSAGE Permission Pattern issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

According to Google's official document

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#add-config

**Your  + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" permission to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the Android application's messages. The permission name must exactly match this pattern—otherwise the Android application will not receive the messages.**

If we declare permission pattern wrong for example: `PACKAGE_NAME.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`

our app should not recieve any notifications. But i can receive notifications. How is it possible?

Does system only looks for a permission ends with `.C2D_MESSAGE`?

Comment: check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121061/c2dm-how-to-use-c2d-message-permission?rq=1) if it can help you :)

Comment: It says recivers looking for ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" so pattern is not important. is this ok?