# Bad class C2D_Message issue xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ADB0010: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl969954024.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #83): Bad class name xx.Droid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE in package xx.Droid] at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A\_work\275\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 345
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\275\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()         0
```

Comment: please read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question so that others can help you

Comment: from next on wards

Answer (score 0):

From April, 2019, google has shut down GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) support.
So I strongly recommend that you should migrate your code to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided sufficient data.
Check your package name again or another silly mistake while adding permission.

Go through this ,it will be helpful:

[C2DM: How to use C2D_MESSAGE permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121061/c2dm-how-to-use-c2d-message-permission)

Answer (score 0):

the FCM library automatically injects the `C2D_MESSAGE` permission into the generated manifest, with your package name as a prefix.Some mobile phone brands don't accept the uppercase letters.

you could add a `Target` to your `.csproj` to fix things up. Note that you need to change the msbuild property `PatchedC2dPermissionName` to have the appropriate value with your package name in lowercase letters in it

you could refer to [C2D_MESSAGE Issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/2402#issuecomment-436976751) and [FixPermission](https://gist.github.com/Redth/9d74a2caaf6654229b5c8c921e30748d)